# Saving images to core data runs of memory

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm trying to do a mass conversion of images to data so it can be stored in core data.
The conversion part works fine, and if I do it without updating core data it shows memory usage at less that 100MB

If I update the core data object, it just keeps consuming memory until the app crashes.

```
func updateLocalImages() {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Picture> = Picture.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "pictureName != \"\"")
    do {
        let pictures = try moc.fetch(fetchRequest)
        print("Picture Update Count: \(pictures.count)")
        for picture in pictures {
            let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
            let path = paths[0]
            if let picName = picture.pictureName {
                let imagePath = path.appendingPathComponent(picName)
                if let uiImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath.path) {
                    if let imageData = uiImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) {
                        autoreleasepool {
                            picture.pictureData = imageData
                            print("Picture Updated")
                            
                            saveContext()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Fetching Failed")
    }
}
```

If I comment out the picture.pictureData = imageData line I don't get the memory issues.

What's the correct way of going about this? There is an unknown number of images (mine current sits at about 5.5GB worth)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reducing memory usage during a loop in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50668015/reducing-memory-usage-during-a-loop-in-swift)

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference. I've tried wrapping both the line causing the issue, plus the whole method but still run out of memory

Comment: You should wrap everything inside the `for` loop with `autoreleasepool`.

Comment: I recommend to leave the pictures in the documents directory – maybe in an extra folder – and save only the file names in Core Data.

Comment: `autoreleasepool` should do the trick though. I used it last month for an issue with CoreData loading heavy data. What's your code with autoreleasepool? But Are you putting the raw data into CoreData, or only the path? It's recommended to just put a path (or any way to construct it back) in CoreData and save the binary somewhere else into your app.

Comment: I'm converting the image to data then storing that in core data. Previously I was storing just the filename but am trying to sync the images across multiple devices.

Comment: @CeriTurner As I mentioned, you need to put everything inside the `for` loop in the `autoreleasepool`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter if it put it before or after the for, the memory usage is the same

Comment: This answer might be of interest, https://stackoverflow.com/a/31815010/9223839

Comment: I'm already doing points 1 and 2. Don't have any knowledge when it comes to point 3